# Receive Test Run start/finish with DTE2 interface in Visual Studio extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

is there a way to subscribe to Test Explorer events in visual studio extension?
I didn't find anything like that in DTE2 interface. My goal is to trigger some function from extension when Test run completed (for the test that were ran from Test Explorer)

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The interfaces you need are available through MEF in the **Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Interfaces.dll** assembly.

You need to expose your extension through MEF and `[Import]` an instance of `IOperationState`, or use the `IComponentModel` interface (returned for the `SComponentModel` service) to access the `IOperationState`. From there, you want to add an event handler to the `IOperationState.StateChanged` event, and look for the `State` property to include the `TestOperationStates.TestExecutionFinished` flag.

I'm terribly sorry for the lack of links, but I couldn't find any information about this in MSDN.

**Edit: Two remarks about compatibility.**

1. This is only available in Visual Studio 2012 and newer.
2. The necessary assembly (mentioned above) has a different strong name in the two versions of Visual Studio, and there is no `bindingRedirect` in Visual Studio 2013. What this means is you will be forced to deploy *separate* extensions for Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2013, or get "clever" about the way you dynamically load your extension code (the latter is way beyond the scope of this answer, but I've used it for some cases like Inheritance Margin extension that requires access to version-specific IntelliSense resources).

**Sample VS 2017**

A sample using MEF and the ITestContainerDiscoverer exported type. But be aware this may be gone in VS 2019!

```
[Export(typeof(ITestContainerDiscoverer))]
[Export(typeof(Testything))]
internal class Testything : ITestContainerDiscoverer
{

    [ImportingConstructor]
    internal Testything([Import(typeof(IOperationState))]IOperationState operationState)
    {
        operationState.StateChanged += OperationState_StateChanged;
     }

    public Uri ExecutorUri => new Uri("executor://PrestoCoverageExecutor/v1");


    public IEnumerable<ITestContainer> TestContainers
    {
        get
        {
            return new ITestContainer[0].AsEnumerable();
        }
    }


    public event EventHandler TestContainersUpdated;

    private void OperationState_StateChanged(object sender, OperationStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.State == TestOperationStates.TestExecutionFinished)
        {
            var s = e.Operation;
        }
    }
}
```

Some more things could be found here
https://www.fuget.org/packages/Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Interfaces/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. wrote a small post about how to do that.

Comment: It works well, thanks. Any idea how to get also resharper events? I only see OperationSetStarted / Finished without any other event between...

Comment: Updated your answer as I am looking on how to do this with an extension I am trying to build. The code posted works based on example used from https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/blob/master/Python/Product/TestAdapter/TestContainerDiscoverer.cs

Answer (score 5):

Thanks 280Z28 for your answer. Working code by using application object DTE:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.Execution;

public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
{            
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider InteropServiceProvider = application as Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider;
    _ServiceProvider = new ServiceProvider(InteropServiceProvider);
    _ComponentModel = (IComponentModel)_ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
    _OperationState = _ComponentModel.GetService<IOperationState>();
    _OperationState.StateChanged += _OperationState_StateChanged;
}

void _OperationState_StateChanged(object sender, OperationStateChangedEventArgs e)
{            
}
```

It is also possible to access currently discovered test by ITestsService.

```
_TestsService = _ComponentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestWindow.Extensibility.ITestsService>();

var GetTestTask = _TestsService.GetTests();
GetTestTask.ContinueWith(Task =>
{
    var DiscoveredTests = Task.Results.ToList();
});
```

Comment: This doesn't fully answer OP's question

Comment: @Verdolino why not? Within the OperationState_StateChanged event one can check for e.State == TestOperationStates.TestExecutionFinished.

Comment: @JoanComasFdz exactly. This is missing from the answer.

Comment: Well, he pasted all the code you need to know the state of the tests. That was the question. The second thing was your "goal".

Comment: As I remember it worked for me on VS2012 Update 3 or 4.